# How To Make Entire 'li' Area and Text A Clickable Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make the entire `li` tag area clickable as well as the text which I have made clickable already. I have tried giving it a `href` property but that doesn't work. I have already set the `li` background to change color when it's hovered over but as I said, how do I also make the entire area clickable? Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lakeside Books</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="masterstyle.css">
    <meta name="viewsize" content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <nav id="nav">
            <h3 id="welcometext">Welcome To<br>Lakeside Books</h3>
            <div id="searchbar">
                <form action="http://www.example.com/search.php">
                    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder=" ...Search Book Title" class="searchstyle"/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <ul>


<li style="background-color: #333">
                    <a href="1Index.html" class="link">
                        Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="2Catgeories.html" class="link">
                        Categories
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://example.com" class="link">
                        Bestsellers
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://example.com" class="link">
                        Contact
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="sectionone">
        <div id="containerone">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="logo">
                    <h1>LAKESIDE BOOKS</h1>
                    <p>KERRYS LOCAL BOOKSTORE</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="sectiontwo">
        <div id="containertwo">
            <h2 id="sectwohead">Best Selling Books Right Now</h2>
                <div id="bestsellerimages">
                    <figure>
                        <img src="Images/4.jpg" alt="book1" height="200" width="131" class="imgbot">
                        <figcaption>The Girl On The Train <br>
                            <span style="font-style: italic; font-size: 0.9em">Paula Hawkins</span></figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="Images/3.jpg" alt="book2" height="200" width="131" class="imgbot">
                        <figcaption>Meet Me In Manhattan <br>
                            <span style="font-style: italic; font-size: 0.9em">Claudia Carroll</span></figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="Images/5.jpg" alt="book1" height="200" width="131" class="imgbot">
                        <figcaption>The Pointless Book 2 <br>
                            <span style="font-style: italic; font-size: 0.9em">Alfie Deyes</span></figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body { /* ### */
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    font-family: Arial, "Open Sans", sans-serif-light, sans-serif, "Segoe UI";
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0 0 0 20%; /* ### */
}
#sidebar {
    background-color: #212528;
    position: fixed;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#nav {
    color: #DADADA;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
#nav ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}
#nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.75em 0 0.75em 0;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
}
#nav li:hover {
    background:#333;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
}
.link {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 25%;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active{
    color: #DADADA;
    text-decoration: none;
}



#welcometext {
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
#searchbar {
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 1em 1em 0.5em 1em;
    text-align: right;
}
#searchbar .searchstyle{
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#searchbar input {
    max-width: 95%;
}
#sectionone {
    /*position: fixed;*/
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 80%;
}
#containerone {
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #DADADA;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -6px 0 0 #fdfdfd, inset 0 -8px 0 0 #DADADA;
}
#header {
    margin: 6em 0 6em 0;
}
#logo h1 {
    color: #ed786a;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    letter-spacing: 13px;
}
#logo p {
    margin-top: -0.6em;
    color: #888888;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}
#sectiontwo {
    width: 80%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#containertwo {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #888888;
}
#sectwohead{
    margin: 2em 0 2em 0;
    color: #888888;
}
#bestsellerimages{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}
#bestsellerimages img{
    padding: 0;
}
#bestsellerimages figure{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 131px;
}
#bestsellerimages figcaption{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
#bestsellerimages figure .imgbot{
    margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}
```

This should help see more clearly what I'm trying to do, as you can see in this image - http://i.imgur.com/OZIt9TM.png - The only clickable area is the blue part within chromes inspect that's easy to see. So what I'm trying to do is make the entire area of that specific 'Home Li' clickable.

Comment: Only one of your anchors have a `href`, what is supposed to happen when you click the others ?

Comment: Once you add a `href` then your problem is solved, notice the first one is clickable, it is because you have the `href there

Comment: I added `href` to bestseller http://jsfiddle.net/hc8douqa/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rule #1 of list-based menus: Style the links, not the wrappers. Only style the list for positioning (display/float etc.).

Use `display:block` on your A-tags and put all styling on that tag, not the list itself.

Home

Move `background-color: #333` to the `.link` class in your css, and add `display:block` to that declaration.

Comment: But OP does have the anchor as block, the problem is the missing `href`, I won't downvote because I know you are going to update your answer

Comment: @Diodeus I'm not sure what you are trying to say I'm afraid. I've updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @SavageSpud -- the idea is to VISUALLY make it look like the whole things is clickable. You do this by making the LI invisible and styling the link itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ups sorry...Try this..

```
#nav li {
   list-style-type: none;
  /* margin: 0; */
  /* padding: 0.75em 0 0.75em 0; */
  /* text-align: center; */
  /* max-width: 100%; */
  /* display: block; */
}

#nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 0;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.75em 0 0.75em 0;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery (assuming the tags are right) you can do it like this without styling the anchor tags:

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
   location.href = $(this).find('a').prop('href'); 
});
```

I would suggest a class name for the ul list like `<ul class="navigation">`

```
$('ul.navigation li').click(function() {
       location.href = $(this).find('a').prop('href'); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your A tag around the LI tag. For example look at the google link. You're putting the A tag around the text only, not the entire element.

```html
<ol>
  <a href="http://google.com"> 
    <li>google</li> <!-- DO THIS -->
  </a>
  <li>
    <a href="http://yahoo.com">yahoo</a> <!-- YOUR CURRENTLY DOING THIS -->
  </li>
</ol>
```